# onSanpshot firebase multiples call REACT

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm make an req from firebase with onsnapshot to detect when there changes in database, but when this happen, my card is rerender multiples times, in picture abellow it is a print of  before i change data in database e after changes.

**BEFORE**
[image]

**AFTER**
[image]

In the second image, this card is red because I changed from status to warning.
these cards in yellow on the second print are previous versions as if saved.

```js
// search from forejein key into props.reference
function GetDocument() {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const [loadingActivities, setLoginActivities] = useState(false);
    var documents: any = [];

    const getDocuments = async (props: any) => {

        for (let i = 0; i < props.ref.length; i++) {
            props.ref[i]
                .onSnapshot((querySnapshot: any) => {
                    // const romaneios = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc: any) => doc.data());
                    const data = { ...querySnapshot.data(), uid: querySnapshot.id }
                    documents.push(data);
                    setLoginActivities(false);
                    if (i === props.ref.length - 1) {
                        props.onComplete(documents);
                    }
                }, (err: any) => {
                    setLoginActivities(false);
                    console.log('erro: ', err);

                });
        }
        return () => {
            const timeout = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 5000);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        };
    }
    return { loadingActivities, getDocuments, setLoginActivities };
}
```

```js
 let ref = references.current;
        documents.getDocuments({
            ref,
            onComplete: (docs: CardProps[]) => {
                loadCard(docs);
    
            },
        });
```

Comment: Why do you have a setTimout and a for loop ? if you look at the docs they are using forEach instead. way cleaner and you don't need to keep track of the loop

Comment: @CyrusZei the timout is to cancel req after 5 seconds and the for it is to each reference that i pass to hook, exemple:: ref is equal the [documents/uid1, documents/uid2].

Comment: I don't believe the issue is in the code you shared, I believe the issue is in your `loadCard()` function, as you might not be clearing the UI from previous cards, and that is why you get a stack of new cards, can you share that code?

Comment: As @RafaelLemos said, might be that you don't clear the array with card items when you fetch those.